# How to kill Toast after exit app?

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

Need some help. I used double click on back button for exit app with Toast with next code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Нажмите еще раз для выхода", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Found that fragment code here at stackoverflow. I guess this is the best solution for issue. But there is one ecxeption - toast is still on screen after exiting app. How to kill the toast when user click back button twice and application closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't kill toast when application closes. We can use toast like below code. `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` less duration of toast when your app closes.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit.. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Or, you can set `Duration` of `Toast` by code below:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press again to exit..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

toast.show();

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
 toast.cancel(); 
 }
}, 500);
```

Or, you can use this :

```
  private Toast toast = null;
  toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        toast.setText("Press again to exit..");
        toast.show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop () {
        super.onStop();
        toast.cancel();

    }
```

Comment: if (toast != null) toast.cancel();

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to reach your goal by Using an `helper class`. In my applications I call this `ToastManager`.

In this class, you will manage every toast of your `application` and you can decide whether to dismiss or show them.

I did it to avoid the `Toast` queue, I'm dismissing the `Toast` when another one is shown.

You can implement it like below and call the `dismissToast method` in your custom `application` or `Activity`.

```
public class ToastManager {
    private static Toast m_currentToast;

    public static void showToast(Context ctx, String text)
    {
        try {
            if (m_currentToast != null) {
                m_currentToast.cancel();
            }
            m_currentToast = Toast.makeText(ctx, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            m_currentToast.show();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void dismissToast(){
      if(m_currentToast != null){
        m_currentToast.cancel();
      }
    }
}
```

Obv you will have to create each tost by calling the showToast method.

hope this helps

Comment: Sure, this is good solution for managint toast, thanks. I will looking forward to implement it, but now i got a simple desigion to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Next code erase toast immediately after closing application:

```
@Override
    protected void onStop () {
        toast.cancel();
        super.onStop();
    }
```

I guess this is enough for my app, it's looking great.
Tnx Abhishek kumar )

Comment: There is one moment here: after exiting app using home button you will get an error unles you check your toast   if (toast != null) toast.cancel();

Comment: What issue are you facing ?

Comment: toast.cancel(); - this method throw nullpointerException if toast doesn't exist. So we need to check it for null befor calling. If you didn't press back button once toast is never created.

Comment: put validation of toast